# LoadLibrary ... failed. missing dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com

I'm creating COM object dll. When I brought it to WIN XP 32 bit macheen and tried to register, I got message: 
`LoadLibrary ... failed. The specified module could not be found`.

When I look at it with dependency walker I found that there are missing 3 dll's:

```
ATL100.dll
MSVCR100D.DLL
DWMAPI.DLL
```

What are the ways of solving this problem? And I don't like that fact that when I install this COM dll to my customers I will also need to take missing dll's together.

Comment: Do research before posting. This was asked million times before. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/845617aa-ab76-4fe1-a658-d020828598b8

Comment: are you missing any runtime libraries?  did you try googling the names of the missing dlls to find out what they are a part of?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the [MS VC++ 2010 redistributable pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555) installed on the client machine.

You should also link your program against the release version of the redist pack and not distribute a debug version of the VC++ runtime (msvcr100d.dll) as its release counterpart is part of the VS2010 redistributable pack, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406807/visual-c-executable-and-missing-msvcr100d-dll). The ATL100.dll is also part of that pack. MS has strict policies about [which dll can be distributed with the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx). A [previous post about DWMAPI.DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173433/how-to-fix-dwmapi-dll-delay-load-dependency-under-winxp) will help to sort out that problem.

Comment: Agreed. MSVCR100D.DLL is not a library that can be legally distributed so the OP needs to make sure everything is being built in release mode before trying to distribute.