# Exception while running WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, windows-xp

I am getting the following error when trying to run a WPF based application on windows XP runs fine on windows 7.

```
System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'dwmapi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Source=***************************
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at Presentation.Common.MetroWindowBase.NativeMethods.DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr , Int32 , Int32& , Int32 )
       at Presentation.Common.MetroWindowBase.HandleSourceInitialized(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Window.OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
       at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
       at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
       at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at *********************
  InnerException:
```

Comment: `dwmapi.dll` copy in your project and add Reference to same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop window manager was introduced in Vista, which is almost certainly why you're unable to load it in XP.

You should look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173433/how-to-fix-dwmapi-dll-delay-load-dependency-under-winxp) to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Its strange that a .net Library that it was using have a dependence of DWM.